# Django Cassandra engine timeout when creating data using models

Tags: django, docker, cassandra

I have a Django app running in a docker swarm. I'm trying to connect it with cassandra using [django-cassandra-engine](http://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/).

Following the guides, I've configured installed apps and connection settings, and running the first step works great (`manage.py sync_cassandra`). It created the keyspace and my models.

However, whenever I try to create data using the models or a raw query, there's simply a timeout while connecting without any other errors.

Swarm is running on AWS with a custom VPC. Docker flow proxy is used as reverse proxy for the setup (not that it should affect the connection in any way)

I've tried deploying cassandra both as a standalone and as a docker image.
I am also able to ping the servers both ways.

I am even able to manually connect to the django app container, install cassandra and connect to the cassandra cluster using `cqlsh`

I've been banging my head off for the past few days around this...

Has anyone encountered something similar? Any ideas as to where I can start digging

Feel free to ask for any information you think may be relevant.